# OOP function and if statement

Tags: php

Not sure if I can ask two questions?

If i run the following function in my database class

```
function generateUserArray() 
{
    $u = array();
    $result = $this->selectAllUsers();
    while( $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
    {
         $u[] = $row['username'];
    }
    return $u;
}
```

Would i call it like this?

```
        $u[] = $datebase->generateUserArray();
```

My second question, will this work:

```
        else if($database->addLeagueInformation($subname, $subformat, $subgame, $subseason, $subwindow, $subadmin, $subchampion, $subtype)
                                            && $databases->addLeagueTable($name) && $_SESSION['players'] == $subplayers && $comp_name =     
                                            "$format_$game_$name_$season" && $_SESSION['comp_name'] = $comp_name)
```

Thankyou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I think you meant

   $u = $datebase->generateUserArray();
2. I think you meant:

   $comp_name == "$format_$game_$name_$season" && $_SESSION['comp_name'] ==$comp_name

The rest looks ok